# Datatables Angular Can't bind to 'dtOptions' error

Tags: angular, datatables

I'm trying to use datatables with angular but I'm getting this error:

Can't bind to 'dtOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'table'

This is part of the settings.component.ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { TableData } from '../md/md-table/md-table.component';
import { DataTables } from 'datatables';

declare var $: any;

declare interface Task {
  title: string;
  checked: boolean;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-settings-cmp',
    templateUrl: 'settings.component.html'
})

export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {


dtOptions: any = {};

ngOnInit() {
  this.dtOptions = {
    ajax: 'api/prodotti/prodotti_all/',
    columns: [{
      title: 'ID',
      data: 'id'
    }, {
      title: 'Code',
      data: 'codice'
    }, {
      title: 'Name',
      data: 'prodotto'
    }]
  };
}

}
```

and this is part of the settings.component.html

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover"> 
           </table>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Can anyone help me please to fix this isuue?

Comment: Did you import the datatable module?

Comment: Hi David, I solved adding DataTablesModule to NgModule imports. Thank you!